# Conic sections are to cones as quadric surfaces are to what?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I just started my Calculus 3 class, which deals mainly with multi-variable Calculus. We went over the different types of 3-D surfaces, mainly Quadric Surfaces (ellipsoids, paraboloids, hyperboloids, etc.) which according to the textbook are "3D analogs of conic sections". I know for conic sections you slice cones with a plane to get ellipses, parabolas, hyperbolas, etc, so I was wondering what is the equivalent for the sliced cone when dealing with these kind of surfaces? How is such a body and the operation of "slicing" it described? And can this be generalized for higher dimensions?

I didn't quite know how to word the problem in a sentence or what field of math it's part of to do a quick google search so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I think [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/Handlin.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwirsIyshIXqAhVHQjABHfXXCasQFjACegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw2_6vykovR0ismHUg9naIM0&cshid=1592265836292) might be of some help to you.

Comment: Cross-posted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363154/conic-sections-are-to-cones-as-quadric-surfaces-are-to-what). When cross-posting, it is important to link the questions together.